# detecting errors in mysqli prepared statement

Tags: php, mysqli, error-handling, prepared-statement

I have a custom error handler in place but I need to know where to test for errors within my prepared statement.

Do I test at all `prepared()` , `bind()`, `execute()` and `store_result()` stages or just selected stages?

```
$statement = $databaseHandler->mysqli->prepare($query) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
$statement->bind_param('s', $userIp) or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
$statement->execute() or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
$statement->store_result() or trigger_error($mysqli->error);
```

Do i even have to check for errors when looking for `num_rows` or would that just be php failing to do a basic job as its no longer communicating with the mysqli server so nothing should go wrong?

What's the point you should stop looking for errors, is it after `execute()`? as `store_result()` not working would be php failing to do its job, which would be the server not actually functioning?

Also I have seen code where the `prepare()` stage is just surrounded in an if statement for errors, by doing this does this mean an error in the other stages would not be handled? Is the prepared stage most likely to go wrong the most?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

AFAIK, you need to convert mysqli errors into PHP errors only for prepare and execute - commands interacting with server. All other commands will emit regular PHP errors already.

There is another method though, but it is quite new and I haven't tested it much. But it is quite tempting, as it will let you get rid of all these trigger errors:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);
```

this simple call  will make mysqli emit PHP errors automatically.

Although it `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT` seems better choice, but it doesn't work for my version yet. While `MYSQLI_REPORT_ALL` would translate mysqli hints as well, which is, on one hand, quite good, but it can spam you with notices like `'No index used in query/prepared statement'`, which is bad. Thus, the only usable setting at the moment is `MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR`

So, you can make it just

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR);

$statement = $db->prepare($query);
$statement->bind_param('s', $userIp);
$statement->execute();
$statement->store_result();
```

**Update**

Finally, I've got the proper usage of `MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT`:

```
mysqli_report(MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);
```

Will make mysqli throw exceptions instead of regular errors.
Exceptions are better than regular errors in many ways: they always contains a **stack trace**, they can be caught using `try..catch` or handled using dedicated error handler. And even unhandled, they act as regular PHP errors providing all the important information, following site-wide error reporting settings.